Questions about the quotient of extended Weyl group and the isomorphism of extended Weyl group
When I am reading a paper An Algebraic Characterization of the Affine Canonical Basis by Beck, Chari, and Pressley, and I have some questions about some notations.
In the paper, we assume that $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra with rank $n$ and $I=\{1,\dotsc,n\}$. Let $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$ be untwisted affine Lie algebra , corresponding to $\mathfrak{g}$ , with index $\hat{I}=\{0,1\dotsc,n\}$.
Let $P=\bigoplus _{i\in I}\mathbb{Z} \omega _i$, $Q=\bigoplus _{i\in I}\mathbb{Z} \alpha _i$,
$P^{\vee}=\bigoplus _{i\in I}\mathbb{Z} \omega _{i}^{\vee}$,
$Q^{\vee}=\bigoplus _{i\in I}\mathbb{Z} \alpha _{i}^{\vee}$ be the weight lattice, root lattice, coweight lattice and coroot lattice, respectively.
Let $W$  and $\hat{W}$ be the Weyl groups of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$. It is well-known that  $W$ is generated by simple reflections $s_i$ for $i\in I$ and $s_i$ for $i\in \hat{I}$,
respectively. The Weyl group $W$ acts on the root lattice $Q$ by extending
$s_i(\alpha_j)=\alpha_j−a_{ij}\alpha_i$.
Then the author says $\hat{W}$ is isomorphic to the semi-direct product $W\ltimes Q$.
The author defines the extended Weyl group $\widetilde{W}\triangleq{} $the semi-direct product $W\ltimes P$. For any $w\in W$, we write $(w,0)\in \widetilde{W}$ and for $\omega\in P$, we write $t_\omega$ for the elements $(1,\omega)$.

The author says $\hat{W}$ is a normal subgroup of $\widetilde{W}$,
then we have $\mathcal{T}=\widetilde{W}/\hat{W}$ is a finite group
isomorphic to a subgroup of the group of diagram automorphisms of
$\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$, i.e. the bijections $\tau: \hat{I}\to \hat{I}$
such that $a_{\tau(i)\tau(j)}=a_{ij}$ for $i,j\in \hat{I}$.
Moreover, there is an isomorphism of groups
$\widetilde{W}=\mathcal{T}\ltimes\hat{W}$, where the semi-direct
product is defined using the action of $\mathcal{T}$ in $\hat{W}$ given by $\tau.s_i = s_{\tau(i)}\tau$.

Here are my questions:

1: Hou could I get $\mathcal{T}=\widetilde{W}/\hat{W}$ is a finite group
which is isomorphic to a subgroup of the group of diagram automorphisms ?
2: How could I understand the isomorphism $\widetilde{W}\cong \mathcal{T}\ltimes\hat{W}$?

Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
I also posted it on MSE Questions about the quotient of extended Weyl group and the isomorphism of extended Weyl group.
New explanations and thoughts:

I have also read details in Chapter $4$  of the book Reflection Groups
and Coxeter Groups written by James E. Humphreys. In $4.5$, the author
writes: 
where $A=$ connected components of $V^\circ:=V\setminus\bigcup_{H\in\mathcal{H}}H$, $\mathcal{H}$ the collection of all hyperplanes $H_{\alpha,k}$ and $A_0:=\{\lambda\in V|0<(\lambda,\alpha)<1\text{ for all }\alpha\in\Phi^+\}.$
I think this is the similar isomorphism from $W\ltimes P\to \mathcal{T}\ltimes
> \hat{W}.$  Is it true?


This is discussed in [B]: Bourbaki - Lie groups and Lie algebras, Chapters 4–6, Ch. VI, §2, no. 3.  (My numbering is from the French version, which is what I've got to hand, but I think it matches the English version.)
Once you have realised $\hat W$ as the subgroup $W \ltimes Q$ of $W \ltimes P = \tilde W$, you have that the inclusion of $P/Q$ in $\tilde W/\hat W$ is an isomorphism.  This is finite, because $P$ and $Q$ are both rank-$n$ lattices.
1: We let $P/Q$ act on the extended Dynkin diagram by acting on an (affine) alcove $C$ in $P \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb R$.  For definiteness, let's choose $C$ so that $0$ is contained in its closure.  Then we can choose $x \in P$, regard it as an element of $\tilde W$, adjust by an element of $Q$ to arrange that the closure of $x C$ also contains $0$, and then adjust by an element of $W$ so that $C$ and $x C$ lie in the same (spherical) chamber, hence (since both contain $0$ in their closure) are equal.  Then all that $x$ can do is permute the vertices of $C$, and this describes its permutation action on $\hat I$.
2: This also realises $\tilde W$ as a semi-direct product, since its quotient $\mathcal T$ can now be seen as the subgroup of $\tilde W$ that preserves $C$.
These actions are described concretely for the various root systems in parts (XII) of Plates I–IX in the back matter of [B].

Thank you for your answer. Maybe I need more time to understand this answer.  Here is another question:  If there is a simple description, for $\left( 1,\omega _{i}^{\lor} \right) \in \widetilde{W}$, we can identify what a element of the form $(a,b)$ where $a\in \mathcal{T} $ and $b\in \hat{W}$, since $W\ltimes P^{\lor}\cong \mathcal{T} \ltimes \widehat{W}$?

@fusheng, re, I guess you switched to $\tilde W=W\ltimes P^\vee$ (instead of $P$)? That is fine; you just need to work in a different apartment. Anyway, yes; as in the answer, after you apply your element of $P$ (or $P^\vee$ if you want to dualise), you apply an element of $\hat W$ to return your chamber to its original postion, and what's left is an element of $\mathcal T$.  If you want to know concretely, for each fundamental weight (or coweight if you want to dualise), what the element of $\mathcal T$ is, then the tables in [B] tell you.

By the way, if you find this answer unsatisfactory, then it is appropriate to unaccept it, so that others will see that you have not yet got the answer you want.  If it is just that you want to spend more time on it, then that's OK, too; you can always re-accept it later.

Thanks!  Maybe I need more time to understand it.

I have also read some details in Chapter $4$
of the book "Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups" written by James E. Humphreys. I also added some new explanations and thoughts.  Is my thoughts correct ?

@fusheng, re, I don't have Humphreys's book available to check the notation, but, yes, that seems to be the same argument.

Thank you so much for answering my question!
